# Initiating a task, navigating away from the app and coming back to see it completed

Tags: android, android-service

...Again on my journey of learning Android Service...

On multiple occasions, I noticed that as a user, you can initiate a task by clicking a button on the app then navigate away from the app. When you come back, you find the task is done. This is done in many apps.

What is the correct design for such behaviour? Is the task being done on UI thread as part of the activity, is it an async task or is it service?

The only thing  I can think of would be a service as this would survive when OS kills the app and thus would be able to complete the task.
However I find it to be over head to use service for everthing.

Comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one good practice is to run whatever asynchronously and store important values on SaveInstance state. for example like so :

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    outState.putBoolean("MYBOOL", true);
    outState.putString("MYSTRING", "Hello World");

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Then on the onCreate Method :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


    if(savedInstanceState != null){

        boolean myBool = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MYBOOL");
        String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MYSTRING");

    }
```

}

That is to store important variables...if you want to refresh any data so when the user gets back finds it loaded, just do it in an async task and on the onPostExecute refresh data notifying any changes to the adapter.

Comment: The problem is what if the application is killed by the OS

Comment: if im not mistaken on saveinstance and onlowmemory are called if the app has not crashed and is being terminated by the OS..you can then store some data in your database which your app check for upon booting, like for example you store current variables and which activity was in use